# Output average grand total by 2 category SQL (Amazon Redshift)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have monthly data that I filter in January 2021. So the data look like this
[image: So the data look like this]

I want to get average grand total by 2 category like the greenbox from the image.
How to make SQL script for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try summing with a case expression eg.

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(
        CASE 
            WHEN Type IN ('Small','Medium') THEN Item
            ELSE 0
        END
    )/2 as AvgGrandTotalFor2Categories
FROM
    my_table
```

or could filter the records you are interested in using a WHERE clause before calculating your average eg.

```sql
SELECT
    SUM(Item)/2 as AvgGrandTotalFor2Categories
FROM
    my_table
WHERE 
    Type IN ('Small','Medium')
```

If there are only these 2 categories, you may not need the WHERE clause after all.

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: It works thank you for your help! Appreciate it.
If i have detail question later about it I will ask you again maybe.
But for now it help my work.

Answer (score 0):

Another way... maybe help you

You can do that using a **SUBQUERYS** lika an example:

*I will use a fake Table because you dont say the name of table and colunms*

```
Select 
   SUM(a.SUM_ITEM)/2 as AVG_FINAL
from    
   (Select 
       Type, 
       sum(item) as SUM_ITEM 
   from YOUR_TABLE 
   group by Type) as a
```

Comment: It also works thank you for your help! Appreciate it.
If i have detail question later about it I will ask you again maybe.
But for now it help my work.